# How can I get a picture, attached to a message in facebook, using facebook API

Tags: facebook, api, message, image

I'm working on an app on ASP.NET, that communicates with facebook through Facebook API. I'm trying to get all messages from facebook:

```
//give access token
var client = new FacebookClient("AAA... ... ...DZD"); 
//get all inbox messages
dynamic messages = client.Get("/me/inbox");
```

And I've got them! But **a few facebook messages have attached pictures**. And I can't get them, because json responce, that I'd received, doesn't contain "link" elements for all these messages. That's odd, cause I can see text and pictures in facebook, and I can get only the text using facebook API.

Can you help me?

Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [View attachments in threads](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/9192430/view-attachments-in-threads)

Comment: (my answer there should be enough info to get the attachments)